# Set the arbitrary coefficients to zero after obtaining a solution form DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

After solving an ODE with 'Solve' function, I'm getting a result as

[image]

Now I know that the coefficients $c_1, c_2$ have to be zero when I impose further restrictions on the solution, so after obtaining the above solution, how I can set the coefficients $c_1, c_2$ to zero so that I will only have the last term on the solution?

Comment: Assuming `sol` is the solution, Try: `sol2 = sol /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0}`

Comment: and if you want to do it for any ode order solution you can try `sol /. C[_Integer] :> 0` btw, the title of your question should be `DSolve` not `Solve`